# Querying s3 data with 1000s of partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have data in s3 upon which an Athena table is built by 2 partition columns. I don't have control over how the data is partitioned in this bucket. To optimize certain queries, I want to copy this data over to a different Athena table which is partitioned by more columns. The problem is that the number of permutations of the different columns, due to the columns' cardinality, is very high, and I run into the 100 concurrent partition limit. Batching the INSERT INTO queries into 100 partitions per batch is not feasible as that will be 50+ queries to run.

So I have 2 options:

- find a way to get around the 100 concurrent partition limit
- find a new data store that will automatically update the table when new partitions are written, similar to what Athena does now.